# Getting value from cell on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get a value from another sheet within the same workbook but I cant seem to figure it out.

I have three sheets; they are named X, Y, and Z. The code I have currently looks at a couple different values on sheet X to determine what cell to pull from on either sheet Y, or Z.

I feel like I have the code written properly but the value I want pulled over just comes up as 0.00 instead of the 1625.00 I want.

```
Sub test()

Dim value1 As String
Dim value2 As String
Dim value3 As String
Dim value4 As Integer

value1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(8, 4).Value '(the letter Y is written in this cell)
value2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(10, 4).Value '(the word yes is written in this cell)
value3 = ActiveSheet.Cells(12, 4).Value '(the word yes is written in this cell)

if value1 = "" Then
Exit Sub
End If

If value2 = "yes" And value3 = "yes" Then
value4 = Worksheets(value1).Range("H4") 
End If

Cells(9, 9) = value4

End Sub
```

Cell H4 on sheet Y contains the number I want pulled over.
I am trying to use the value1 string as the name of the sheet as I may need to pull from either sheet Y, or Z

Comment: `Cells(9, 9).Value = Worksheets(value1).Range("H4").Value`?

Comment: Most likely `value2` and `value3` aren't actually both "yes".

Comment: Check for spaces before and after the word. If there are, either remove them or wrap the variable assigning with a `trim()`

Comment: Use the debugger and step thru your code (use F8). Check the content of the variables, this should show you why your code fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Various Issues

- Here is something to play with.
- If you qualify the workbook and worksheets, it will make it easier to follow what is happening i.e. no need for `ActiveSheet` (you should avoid it like the plague) when you know that the worksheet is worksheet `X`.
- Be careful when comparing strings e.g. "A"<>"a" or "Yes"<>"yes".
- Sometimes you're better off not writing a value to a variable.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Val1 As String
    Dim Val2 As String
    Dim Val3 As String
    Dim Val4 As Long
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook containing this code.
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("X") ' X or x will equally be accepted.
    
    Val1 = ws.Cells(8, 4).Value  ' (the letter Y is written in cell 'D8')
    Val2 = ws.Cells(10, 4).Value ' (the word yes is written in cell 'D10')
    Val3 = ws.Cells(12, 4).Value ' (the word yes is written in cell 'D12')
    'Val1 = ws.Range("D8").Value  ' (the letter Y is written in cell 'D8')
    'Val2 = ws.Range("D10").Value ' (the word yes is written in cell 'D10')
    'Val3 = ws.Range("D12").Value ' (the word yes is written in cell 'D12')
    
    If Val1 = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' StrComp with vbTextCompare will allow Yes, yes, yEs, yeS...
    If StrComp(Val2, "yes", vbTextCompare) = 0 And _
       StrComp(Val3, "yes", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        Val4 = wb.Worksheets(Val1).Range("H4").Value
        ' You could have just used:
        'ws.Cells(9, 9).Value = wb.Worksheets(Val1).Range("H4").Value
        ' i.e. because when you declare as Long it means there will be trouble
        ' if the value is not a number.
    End If
    
    ws.Cells(9, 9).Value = Val4 ' Cell 'I9'

End Sub
```